# Ion-toggle (ngModelChange) prints wrong output

Tags: angular, ionic2, ion-toggle

this is my .html file

```
<ion-item no-lines (click)="update()" >
        <ion-label> Notification</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="notify" (ngModelChange)="update()"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

this is my .ts file

```
notify:boolean = true;

update(){
  consol.log(this.notify);
}
```

> when i click on the `Notification` text i am printing `true`
>
> When i click on the `ion-toggle` it prints me `false`

When i click on the ion-toggle it prints opposite of the boolean but i am not changing anything any idea about this issue.

Comment: is it an issue ? toggle action is supposed to change the value.."A toggle technically is the same thing as an HTML checkbox input, except it looks different and is easier to use on a touch device."

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toggle/Toggle/

Comment: yes if you see the notify variable is update from get request and because of that i am using ngmodelchange and then my ngmodel change is printing opposite of the notify varibale but my click funtion is working fine @suraj

Comment: so it is printing after the click which changes true to false..notify is the `ngModel`..not really getting you

Comment: i have one funtion invoking on diffrent action if you see my html code you will get `(click)` and another one is `(ngModelChange)` invoking the same function when i click on the `(click)` i am printing the same data available in the `notify` variable but when i click on the `(ngModelChange)` i am getting printed the opposite value from the notify @suraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the **[`ionic docs`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toggle/Toggle/)**

Try to remove/rename the function update in the

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="notify" (ngModelChange)="update()"></ion-toggle>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/RESd3cathLdqSI5zJ2NL?p=preview)**

Comment: ion-toggle is updated from the ts file when the page appeares and because of that ionchange is automatically invoking the function

Comment: @MohanGopi what is the issue now?

Comment: yes the click function is printing me correctly but my ngModelchange is printing opposite of the notify variable

Comment: did you try with ionchange?

Comment: yes if you see the notify variable is update from get request and because of that i am invoking the funtion automatically so  i am using ngmodelchange and then my ngmodel change is printing opposite of the notify varibale but my click funtion is working fine

Comment: ion-change is invoking automatically for the first time without any user action so only i choose ngmodelchange

Comment: can you remove <ion-item no-lines (click)="update()" > update from here and try

Comment: i removed the `(click)=update()` and tried but still i am getting the false printed in my console but my notify variable is in true before invoking the funtion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141554/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-mohan-gopi).